# Twitter : how to get the last tweet time?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-timeline

I can include the twiiter API . But I have to show the LAST TWEET TIME of that account. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would call [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) to retrieve the tweets of the user in question.  Grab the first tweet off the timeline, which will be the most recent one, and read the "created_at" property.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = "twitterusername";
$notweets = 1;
$consumerkey = "12345";
$consumersecret = "123456789";
$accesstoken = "123456789";
$accesstokensecret = "12345";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo $tweets[0]->created_at;
```

Twitter library can download from [here](http://www.webdevdoor.com/downloads/twitteroauth-master.zip)

I got from http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth